# Python Pandas: How to change all the values in the column where the value contains a specific word

Tags: python, pandas

New to python - I am trying to change all the values in one of the columns in my data frame where the text contains "employed or Employed" word. Should i use the lambda function to loop through the column? If no, then what's the most optimal way to do this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Self-employed',1,1],
    ['Self employed contract labour',1,1],
    ['Self Employed',1,0],
    ['N/A(Self employed)',1,0],
    ['SELF EMPLOYED',1,0]
], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df
```

Expected Output:

```
    ['Self Employed',1,1],
    ['Self Employed',1,1],
    ['Self Employed',1,0],
    ['Self Employed',1,0],
    ['Self Employed',1,0]
```

Comment: the question is too vague, please provide an example of the DataFrame and the matching expected output

Comment: Added the data frame

Comment: OK (although not valid python, the quotes are missing), but more importantly the logic and expected output are still missing

Comment: Added expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `str.contains` and boolean indexing should do the trick:

```
df.loc[df['A'].str.contains('employed', case=False), 'A'] = 'Self Employed'
```

output:

```
               A  B  C
0  Self Employed  1  1
1  Self Employed  1  1
2  Self Employed  1  0
3  Self Employed  1  0
4  Self Employed  1  0
```

Comment: can i add a regex here in place of 'employed'? ------- df.loc[df['A'].str.contains('ENTER REGEX HERE?', case=False), 'A'] = 'Self Employed'

Comment: Yes you can, by default `str.contains` uses a regex

Comment: Regex Works like a charm :-)